# How can I fill in turtle directions in a list using Python?

Tags: python, list, fill, turtle-graphics, directions

I have a list of turtle directions:

```
redlist = ['seth(0)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(0)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(90)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(90)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(180)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(180)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(270)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(270)', 'forward(drawdist)']
```

How can I fill this in using the list?

Answer (score 0):

Although a list of syntactically correct Python statements like this seems like an opportunity to use `eval()`, resist that temptation.  The syntax here is simple enough, function with one argument, that we can use the `re` module to parse the commands and only execute what appear to be valid functions against valid arguments:

```
import turtle
import re

redist = [ \
    'seth(0)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(0)', 'forward(drawdist)', \
    'seth(90)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(90)', 'forward(drawdist)', \
    'seth(180)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(180)', 'forward(drawdist)', \
    'seth(270)', 'forward(drawdist)', 'seth(270)', 'forward(drawdist)' \
    ]

valid_functions = { \
    'seth': turtle.setheading, \
    'forward': turtle.forward, \
    }

valid_arguments = { \
    'drawdist': 50, \
    }

turtle.begin_fill()

for command in redist:
    match = re.match(r"^(\w+)\((\w+)\)$", command)

    if match is None:
        raise SyntaxError("Invalid syntax")

    function, argument = match.group(1), match.group(2)

    if function not in valid_functions:
        raise ValueError("Invalid function")

    if argument in valid_arguments:
        argument = valid_arguments[argument]
    elif argument.isdigit():
        argument = int(argument)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Invalid argument")

    valid_functions[function](argument)

turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.mainloop()
```

For those who want to read ahead, it draws a filled square.  The exceptions I raise above may not be the correct ones but the point is that you need to error check everything, and raise exceptions, when attempting to execute code that's been handed to you as a string.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pendown`, then the `fillcolor` method in a loop:

```
def draw_n_fill(self,redlist):
  self.pendown()
  [self.getAttr(entry)() for entry in redlist] 
  self.fillcolor("red")
```

**References**

- [How to draw a ring of colors using turtle module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437360/1113772)
- [Python: Using Turtles for Drawing Circles](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/06/python-using-turtles-for-drawing/)
- [Summary of Turtle Methods](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/IntroPythonTurtles/Summary/summary.html)

Comment: This answer doesn't work nor address the OP's question.  The references are off-base.  (There are no rings, colors nor circles in OP's question.)  Turtles don't have a `getAttr()` method so that causes an exception.