# How to draw a ring of colors using turtle module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which is supposed to draw a ring of colors around a circle but only one color if printed and changed 8 times before moving to the next

```
import turtle

def drawCircle(colorList, radius):
    for color in colorList:
        turtle.color(color)
        for i in range(len(colorList)):
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setpos(0, -radius)
            xpos=turtle.xcor()
            ypos=turtle.ycor()
            head=turtle.heading()
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.home()
            turtle.setpos(xpos,ypos)
            turtle.setheading(head)
            turtle.circle(radius)
            turtle.end_fill()
            turtle.penup()
    return

colorList=["#880000","#884400","#888800","#008800",\
        "#008888","#000088","#440088","#880088"]

drawCircle(colorList,200)
```

How would I make it that each arc around the circle is a different color. [here is an example](http://www.hgtv.com/decorating-basics/color-wheel-primer/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need something like this

```
def drawSegment(color,x, y, r, angleStart, angleEnd, step=1):
    #More efficient to work in radians
    radianStart = angleStart*pi / 180
    radianEnd   = angleEnd*pi / 180
    radianStep=step *pi/180

    #Draw the segment
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(x,y)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.pendown()
    for theta in arange(radianStart,radianEnd,radianStep):
        turtle.setpos(x + r * cos(theta), y + r * sin(theta))

    turtle.setpos(x + r * cos(radianEnd), y + r * sin(radianEnd))
    turtle.setpos(x, y);
    turtle.end_fill()

def drawCircle(colorList,radius):
    #do something to draw an equal segment for each color advancing it around 360 degree's
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer has too many parameters to pass than what was I previously intended for. I only need to pass two parameters `color` and `radius`. color being the list of colors and radius being the radius of the circle so the function would be called like `drawCircle(colorList, 200)`

Comment: yeah ... thats easy to do ... but im pretty sure this is some sort of learning excersize, so I left it up to you to implement that function, once you know you need to use this function ... if you want to learn anything you will need to figure out how to apply this function in order to create the interface you want